# Load header and footer view in CI

Tags: templates, codeigniter

Is there any way to load view 'header'/'footer' without calling `$this->load->view('header')` or `$this->load->view('footer')` in every controller? Maybe a template that can be use in every view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a couple simple approaches to get you started:

#### Create a template class:

```
class Template {

    function load($view)
    {
        $CI = &get_instance();
        $CI->load->view('header');
        $CI->load->view($view);
        $CI->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

Usage in controller:

```
$this->template->load('my_view');
```

#### Use a master view file:

```
<!-- views/master.php -->
<html>
  <header>Your header</header>
  <?php $this->load->view($view, $data); ?>
  <footer>Your footer</footer>
</html>
```

In the controller:

```
$this->load->view('master', array(
    'view' => 'my-view-file',
    'data' => $some_data
));
```

---

I prefer the `Template` class approach, as it's easy to add methods to append templates areas, load javascript files, and whatever else you need. I also prefer to automatically select the view file based on the method being called. Something like this:

```
if ( ! isset($view_file)) {
    $view_file = $CI->router->fetch_class().'/'.$CI->router->fetch_method();
}
```

This would load `views/users/index.php` if the controller is `Users` and the method is `index`.

Comment: where should I create this class,.?

Comment: Put it in `application/libraries` as `template.php`. Extend it with methods like `set_area('header', $file)` or `set_template('three_column')`... Just keep it simple and build what you need as you go. You can do an audit later and clean it up.

Comment: I had to add $autoload['libraries'] = array('Template', 'database'); into application/config/autoload.php . The template-solution worked for me after that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to load view files somehow, this the way CI use to include the files.

Stick to the standard, I think it's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that loads header and footer and places data in between.

Anyway the model on which CI is built requires the explicit loading of views (afaik).

Answer (score 0):

I usually extend CI's Loader class to accomplish this...

```
<?php
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE, $include_header = TRUE, $include_footer = TRUE)
    {
        $content = '';

        if ($include_header)
        {
            $content .= parent::view('header', $vars, $return);
        }

        $content .= parent::view($view, $vars, $return);

        if ($include_footer)
        {
            $content .= parent::view('footer', $vars, $return);
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```