# Codeigniter Message: Undefined variable: query

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, show

SOLVED!

thanks to Fabio i realized that i missed something in my index function of my controller.

---

i am working on a view that show's me the data from the database.

Now i get the error: Message: Undefined variable: query.

my Model:

```
<?php
class categorieen_model extends CI_Model{

    function categorieen_getall()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->get('Categorieen');

        return $query->result();
    }
}

?>
```

My controller

```
public function get_All()
{
    $this->load->model('categorieen_model');
    $data['query'] =
    $this->categorieen_model->categorieen_getall();

    $this->load->view('sidebar', $data);
}
```

My view

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
    <?php echo $row->Categorie; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Last week i tried this with the same database, another table and other data and names in my controllers/views and it worked. when i changed it today to my new table it did not work anymore.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Does the query return any rows. Try doing a `print_r($query->result());` before you return the results;

Comment: It does'nt show any rows so i will try your suggestion

Comment: i forgot to tell i have another error. i posted it above

Comment: Sounds like your query doesn't return any results, and so the array passed to the view holds no data, and can't be looped through.

Comment: Don't know why this happens because there is data in my table and i Thought the code was good.

Comment: Are you sure you're querying the right database? have you checked config/database.php?  Because if print_r($query->result()); doesn't return any values the problem must be somewhere between the model and the database

Comment: i figured out what the problem is. when i route to http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/get_All i can see the records. but when i load the view on my homepage in a div called sidebar it does not work. how can i show the rows in my sidebar on my mainmage?

Comment: are you loading two views? Can you post the code of both controller methods?

Comment: i think so. >.< because of your comment i'v got an idea will look at it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing any data on the index method to the views

```
<?php
  class Home extends CI_Controller{

    public function index() {
      //add this code
      $this->load->model('Categorieen_Model');
      $data['query'] = $this->Categorieen_Model->categorieen_getall();
      $this->load->vars($data);
      //end of new code
      $this->load->view('header');
      $this->load->view('navmenu');
      $this->load->view('sidebar');
      $this->load->view('home');
      $this->load->view('sidebar2');
      $this->load->view('sidebar3');
      $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function get_All(){
      $this->load->model('Categorieen_Model');
      $data['query'] = $this->Categorieen_Model->categorieen_getall();

      $this->load->view('sidebar', $data);
    }

  }
?>
```

Comment: allright. i am very stupid. please hit me with a stick. thanks so much :D accepted

Comment: No problem at all, by the way instead of loading all that views, in every method you could adopt a "templating" system, in this answer I gave a very basic way of do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093949/call-1-view-in-code-ignighter-but-share-header-footer-amoung-all-views/15094144#15094144

And you also have this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601054/load-header-and-footer-view-in-ci

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your controller:

```
<?php 
if(is_array($query) && count($query)  > 0 ) { ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
    <?php echo $row->Categorie; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: `&& count($query)  > 0` is odd here. If there're no elements loop body will never execute.

Comment: You mean views? and this doesn't work either. still the same error.

Comment: Hmm something changed now. the second error is gone. but the first error is still showing up

Comment: Can you help me any further with this?

Answer (score -1):

Change your controller to this

```
public function get_All()
{
    $this->load->model('categorieen_model');
    $data['list'] =
    $this->categorieen_model->categorieen_getall();

    $this->load->view('sidebar', $data);
}
```

And change view to

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($list as $row){?>
    <?php echo $row->Categorie; ?>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. get the same error only list is different Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: list